# How to move up two UIViews when keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, uiview, nsnotificationcenter

I have two UIViews and UIView2 got UITextView which can be placed wherever user likes to add Text label. And when user places UiTextView in the bottom, keyboard appears to type text and UITextView moves up. And it works great! I need also move UIView1 which is under the UIView1.

UIView2 is property of UIView1 and i need Notify UIView1 to do Move Up methods for it when UITextView of UIView2 becomeFirstResponder.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.drawingView
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.drawingView
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Your controller needs to handle the notification, not the view. Then the controller moves the view. Did you look at the myriad of other answers to this question? See the related questions list.

Answer (score 2):

You've add notification for keyboard Events then what you have to do is to implement the method keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide. See below

```
 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
/*
 Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
 */
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
// Get the origin of the keyboard when it's displayed.
NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
// Get the top of the keyboard as the y coordinate of its origin in self's view's coordinate system. The bottom of the text view's frame should align with the top of the keyboard's final position.
CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
// Get the duration of the animation.
NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
[animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];
// Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
[self moveCommentBarViewWithKeyBoardHeight:keyboardRect.size.height withDuration:animationDuration];
```

}

```
 - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
/*
   Restore the size of the text view (fill self's view).
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the disappearance of the keyboard.
 */
NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
[animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];
[self moveCommentBarViewWithKeyBoardHeight:0 withDuration:animationDuration];
}
```

hope it could hlep:)

PS: when add this notification, you better add to method -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animite. And  use

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

to removew observe when viewWillDisappear.

```
 -(void)moveCommentBarViewWithKeyBoardHeight:(CGFloat)kHeighy withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)animationD
 {
 CGRect tempRect = commentEditedBarView.frame;
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationD];

 [commentEditedBarView setFrame:CGRectMake(tempRect.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-kHeighy-tempRect.size.height, tempRect.size.width, tempRect.size.height)];
 [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have Those methods keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide. I call those methods of UIView2 from UIView1 via NSNotification. But i try do do the same in UIView1 but UITextView belongs to UIView2.

Comment: no its not what you have, its you have to implement your method. See those method i gave you. OK i forgot given u the method to move your view. i added to my answer right now.

Comment: As I said, it works great for UIView2(self.drawingView) but i cant move UIView2

Comment: see my method. you can rewrite my method like this  -(void)moveCommentBarViewWithKeyBoardHeight:(UIView*)aView to get the handle of the superview of textField you are going to move, so that wherever the textView you put, you could make the super one to move.